# How to replace/substitute any recurring class or method name with shorter or simpler string in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, replace, substitution

Ok, so what I want to do is assign an alternate name to long series of recurring class or object name. For example

```
public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Hello k= new Hello();
      k.HelloWorld();
    }
}
class Hello
{
   public void HelloWorld()
   {
       System.out.println("Hello World");
   }
}
```

so what i want to happen here is I want to keep the name of the method "HelloWorld" as it is but i want to access "HelloWorld" from main method using "HW"(say), so that I can write

```
 k.HW();
```

to call "HelloWorld" without having to add more than 2 lines of code.

I know its trivial but I am only being curious and want to know if it is possible.

Comment: create a method `HW` that points to `HelloWorld`. but obviously this is a terrible idea. `public void HW() { HelloWorld(); }` done on 1 line.

Comment: What really is your problem ??

Comment: keep in mind short and cryptic method names is just bad code. dont sacrifice clarity for shortness.

Comment: Please, don't do that!  I guarantee you will look at that code in a month and have no idea what it is doing!

Comment: Java is designed to be wordy, a bit tedious to write, but "easy to read".  One can argue how well they succeeded.  But naming all your classes with two-letter abbreviations to save a little typing is not Java style.  Nor is it a good idea.  When you come back to that code 6 months later will you remember all the abbreviations?  How much time will it take training a new hire?

Comment: I just was curious if it was possible or not, I would not do it professionally

Comment: if you want to separate internal methods from external methods, use access modifiers private/protected internally, public externally. it makes no sense why you would ever want 2 public names for exactly the same function. it's always hard to answer a question where your intention is not specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At compile time, the invocated method has to match to the exact name of the existing method.
So you have to write :

```
Hello k= new Hello();
k.HelloWorld();
```

Keeping meaningful names is important.

Now modern IDEs help you.
You can write something of similar and then the auto completion mechanism may help you to by proposing the matching method.

For example with Eclipse, by typing :

`k.hw` + `ctrl space` (default autocompletion key), Eclipse will search methods in the `Hello` class that start by `h` (upper or lowercase) and that have then a `W` uppercase character.
So it will propose this method (`HelloWorld()`) and you would have only to select it so that it completes the code with the method invocation.

Comment: That's a very cool trick, Thanks, I am sure many modern compilers have this feature, and I will surely use it

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the IDE you are using there is a restriction to do that.

There are tools like Lombok (https://projectlombok.org) that allows you to stop writing  getters and setters methods  on classes  so, your POJOs gets smaller, but then you can call any getter or setter from anywhere.

But that is an IDE modification.

If you want to do that at runtime you can do it using reflection and Javassist.

Javassist allows you to create and modify Classes at runtime, you could add your HW() method programmatically and then call it with Reflection (Method.invoke())

Comment: intelliJ lets you select a variable, then press alt + enter, and automatically create getter and setter. im sure theres a similar functionality in eclipse.

Comment: Yes there is. Lombok is intended for not hardcoding getters and setters. Very useful to increment Code Coverage.

Comment: That is a very impressive technique but the question is.... Does it solve the issue in 2 or fewer lines of code? And How efficient is it?

Comment: you havent clearly specified what the issue is. what are you trying to achieve? your question is devoid of all context. explain what it is you're trying to do, and more importantly, why

Comment: I mentioned lombok because, at least as far as I understand, what you want to do is have abbreviated methods that refer to the actual methods that exist in your code. To do that in development time you have to have a modified IDE that allows this type of trick.